# On heap and on stack application issue

Tags: c++, winapi

I create System object on heap and inside the system class I create Game object on heap while KeyboardServer object on stack.

1) Do KeyboardServer object will behave like on heap as System object is part of it?

2) Does KeyboardServer object needs to be created on heap too?

3) Do any better solution to increase the performance?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: main.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "SystemClass.h"

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pScmdline, int iCmdshow )
{
    SystemClass* System;
    bool result;

    // Create the system object
    System = new SystemClass;
    if ( !System )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Initialize and run the system object
    result = System->Initialize();
    if (result)
    {
        System->Run();
    }

    // Shutdown and release the system object
    System->Shutdown();
    delete System;
    System = 0;

    return 0;
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: SystemClass.h
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifndef _SYSTEMCLASS_H_
#define _SYSTEMCLASS_H_


///////////////////////////////
// PRE-PROCESSING DIRECTIVES //
///////////////////////////////
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN


//////////////
// INCLUDES //
//////////////
#include <Windows.h>


///////////////////////
// MY CLASS INCLUDES //
///////////////////////
#include "GameClass.h"
#include "KeyboardClass.h"


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class name: SystemClass
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SystemClass
{
    public:
    SystemClass();
    ~SystemClass();

    bool Initialize();
    void Shutdown();
    void Run();

    LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler( HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam );

private:
    void InitializeWindows();
    void ShutdownWindows();

private:
    LPCSTR m_applicationName;
    HINSTANCE m_hinstance;
    HWND m_hwnd;

    GameClass*            m_Game;
    KeyboardServerClass  m_KeyboardServer;
};


/////////////////////////
// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES //
/////////////////////////
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam );


/////////////
// GLOBALS //
/////////////
static SystemClass* ApplicationHandle = 0;

#endif



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: KeyboardClass.h
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifndef _KEYBOARDCLASS_H_
#define _KEYBOARDCLASS_H_


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class prototype
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class KeyboardServerClass;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class name: KeyboardClientClass
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class KeyboardClientClass
{
public:
    KeyboardClientClass( const KeyboardServerClass& KeyboardServer );
    ~KeyboardClientClass();

    bool KeyIsPressed( unsigned char keycode ) const;

private:
    const KeyboardServerClass& server;
};

class KeyboardServerClass
{
    friend KeyboardClientClass;

public:
    KeyboardServerClass();

    void OnKeyPressed( unsigned char keycode );
    void OnKeyReleased( unsigned char keycode );

private:
    static const int nKeys = 256;
    bool keystates[ nKeys ];
};

#endif
```

Comment: And that's why the notion of "heap" and "stack" is more confusing than it's worth, and generally inadequate.

Comment: There is no `KeyboardServerClass` object allocated on the stack in your code.

Comment: Sorry. Already added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Do KeyboardServer object will behave like on heap as System object is part of it?

No, `KeyboardServer` is part of the `SystemClass`, not vice versa.

> 2) Does KeyboardServer object needs to be created on heap too?

It is created automatically:

`m_KeyboardServer` is part of `SystemClass`. When you create `SystemClass`, it will create `KeyboardServerClass` object.

So, when you create `SystemClass` object on the heap, it will create `m_KeyboardServer` on the heap automatically for you.

Imagine this scenario:

```
class A
{
   int field;
};

A *a = new A();
A b;
```

Here, object `a` is created on the heap, and so is its member `field`. Object `b` is created on stack, and so `b.field` is.

Also, imagine this:

```
class A
{
    Object* obj;
}
```

If you create object of this class on the stack, **the pointer** to the `Object` will be allocated on the stack. The complete `Object` where this pointer will point to may be on the heap, may be on the stack, in some file, etc., but the part of the class is **the pointer to the Object** and that will be stored in the same location where the entire object of `class A` is stored.

> 3  Do any better solution to increase the performance?

If you have *m_KeyboardServer and if you always allocate new instance manually, then it will not be slower than having the entire object in the class, which will automatically initialize one for you. However, if you don't need to have a different instance of KeyboardServer (if you want to share one between different SystemClass objects, then you should go with pointer, as it will create only a pointer for each instance of `SystemClass`.

Comment: So, although I design m_KeyboardServer object as on stack, does it still creates m_KeyboardServer object as on heap when I create System class object as on heap?

Comment: @user Yes. However, I don't know what do you mean by: "design m_KeyboardServer as on stack"? Do you think that because you don't have a pointer to `KeyboardServer` in the `System` class, but the complete object?

Comment: Ya. I use KeyboardServerClass  m_KeyboardServer rather than KeyboardServerClass*  m_KeyboardServer in System class. Does it has any different on the aspect of performance?

Comment: If you have `*m_KeyboardServer` and if you always allocate new instance manually, then it will not be slower than having the entire object in the class, which will automatically initialize one for you. However, if you don't need to have a different instance of `KeyboardServer` (if you want to share one between different `SystemClass` objects, then you should go with pointer.

Comment: So, KeyboardServerClass* m_KeyboardServer is faster than KeyboardServerClass m_KeyboardServer in this scenario?

Comment: Do you need different KeyboardServerClass for the each System object? If so, it is not faster, as you will still need to allocate one by yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37389/discussion-between-user-and-nemanja-boric)